# Spring4 Junit4 Test: @TransactionConfiguration VS @Transactional, use only one or together?

Tags: spring, transactions, junit4

In My junit test case:

1. I use only @transactional at class or one, each test method will roll back, because each method within running a transaction. And I add it at method, then the assigned method will roll back.
2. I use only @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true) at class, but the transaction is not work.
3. I use @transaction and @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true) at class together, also it will be roll back.

My issue:

1. Why roll back is not work with only @TransactionConfiguration at class?
2. I see @transactional default bean name is transaction manager and roll back is TRUE, so i only add it at class and not @TransactionConfiguration?
3. @transactional must annotation, is @TransactionConfiguration only assign transaction manager in multi-transactionManager case?

Answer (score 0):

1. @transactional causes each method to be run within a transaction, and you can configuration, isolation etc by @transactional.
2. You can configuration transaction manager with @TransactionManager in multi-TransactionManager. So transaction is not work if you only use this annotation.
3. Because each method to be run within a transaction, then you can change it with @RollBack(false).

Answer (score -1):

In https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionConfiguration.html,  They say @TransactionConfiguration is "Deprecated" and "As of Spring Framework 4.2, use @Rollback or @Commit at the class level and the transactionManager qualifier in @Transactional".